# using INSERT query and SELECT

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE categories
 (
   ID serial PK,
   description varchar(20)
 );

CREATE TABLE commissions 
 (
    categoryID integer references categories(ID),
    percent varchar(20)
 );
```

I want to add a row to the commissions table for the category whose description is Widgets, so that the commission is ten percent. Assume that the category already exists in the categories table.

I tried :

```
INSERT INTO commissions (categoryID, percent)
 VALUES ( categoryID, 10)
SELECT ID FROM categories WHERE description = 'widgets';
```

But is not correct, Can someone help me out of how to insert a value plus getting another value from another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax in this case is:

```
INSERT INTO commissions (categoryID, percent)
SELECT ID, 10 FROM categories WHERE description = 'widgets';
```

You don't use `VALUES` when you use `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO commissions (categoryID, percent)

            SELECT ID,10 FROM categories WHERE description = 'widgets'
```

**Values** Keyword **cant be used** while doing a **Insert-Into-Select** operation.